# Who are responsible for manage Tor directory servers?

Tags: relays, onion-routing

Many documents says that a user that use tor network should connect to **tor directory server**  to make circuit.

1. Who is responsible for manage Tor directory servers?
2. if there are some people who is relevant with police, government or hacker group, how can we trust tor directory server?
3. Relay nodes are important in tor network for many reason. sometimes they are removed and joined newly. which algorithm(mechanism) is used for this work? if admin(answer of 1st question) should manually manage this work, it's very worst.

Sorry for my English. have a nice day.

Comment: Who removes tor relays? I've never heard of this.

Comment: @Birb The Tor people will remove relays if they are harming the network or are very out-of-date. For example: https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-relays/2019-October/017795.html